# Implementation of Momentum: inconsistency in formulas

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

It seems that there are inconsistencies in the formulas recommended by various authors for how to implement momentum in SGD.

Andrew Ng in the deep_learning_ai courses is inconsistent between his slides and the assignment:

Avoiding Greek letters, my notation is:

```
v = momentum term  
B = beta, momentum parameter (typically in 0.8 to 0.99)  
th = vector of theta parameters for some layer  
d_th = partial derivative of cost relative to theta parameters  
a = alpha  (learning rate, sometimes called nu by other authors)
```

assignment:

```
v = B*v + (1 - B)*d_th  
th = th - a*v
```

slides:

```
v  = B*v + d_th  
th = th - a*v
```

The difference here is that Ng leaves out the 1-B term of the moving average in slides.  Many authors do this on the assumption that (1-B) is small for useful values of B and we still get a moving average because we are going to substract a*d_th to get our updated th.  The difference is a*(1 - B)*d_th, which might be as little as .009 of d_th.  Considering how "rough and ready" SGD is, it comes out in the wash.

The bigger point here is that Ng multiplies the momentum term, v, times the learning rate in the update of theta.

Karpathy, one of Ng's long ago Phd students at Stanford does it this way in his notes for CS231n:

```
v = B*v + a*d_th  
th = th - v
```

Leaving aside the (1-B) term of the moving average of d_th, the difference from Ng is that alpha (a) is multiplied times the partial of theta, d_th, but NOT times first term of the moving average for momentum, v. This approach seems far more common.

When you consider that reasonable values of alpha might be 0.01 or 0.001, then the Ng way would be tantamount to using a B of, say, 0.01 * 0.9 = 0.009.

One author I found tried to resolve this by suggesting that alpha should be scaled by the term 1 / (1 - B) equivalent to muliplying alpha by 10 (if B is 0.9) or 100 (if B is 0.99).

I could not algebraically reduce one form to the other.

What is the correct approach?

Momentum is the simplest of the "optimization" methods, but the same inconsistency appears for rmsprop, Nesterov momentum, ADAM, etc.

Thanks,
Lewis

Comment: Geoffrey Hinton, in the deep learning class from U Toronto, implements momentum the way Ng does in the assignments. So, that must be the right way...

Comment: I find this blog [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/stochastic-gradient-descent-with-momentum-a84097641a5d) They claim at one form of formula this: This is pretty much identical to the first pair of equation, the only difference is that you need to scale learning rate by (1 - beta) factor.